# jQuery - Scroll sidebar

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to create a sidebar that scrolls with the page. But I want it to start scrolling after user has scrolled to the top border of the sidebar.

(The way facebook does it on the front page and the adds scroll with user) and on [this](http://www.feissarimokat.com/) site (if you scroll to bottom of the page, one of the adds is always following you)

and I'm wondering how would I achieve it.

I've tried the following snippet, but this begins the scroll instantly and is not going to work with liquid layout, as I want the sidebar to stay in the same place and only scroll down.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $("#sidebar").css("position", "fixed").css("top", "50px").css("right", "50px");         
});​
```

And a related [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ChristianNikkanen/xg54b/)

Answer (score 0):

define `minHeight`

```
minHeight = YOUR-FAVORITE-HEIGHT-IN-PIXEL-WITHOUT' px';
```

In `scroll` event, do all you want after checking this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > minHeight) {
   // change sidebar style, blah blah blah...
}esle{
   // roll back sidebar style, blah blah blah...
}
```

**EDIT:**

set `minHeight` to `$('#sidebar').offset().top;`

Comment: What? I can't use pixels on a liquid layout

Comment: @Christian I was reviewing my old answers, It is funny that my answer was exactly what you accept it (just take a look at tutorial), but you downvote mine!

Comment: Sorry about that, I must have been high or something.