# Make a floated div scroll up/down with page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got your stereotypical two column (1 content, 1 sidebar) layout with each column floated opposites and all that. But I need my sidebar to scroll with the page. My first instinct was to use `position:fixed`, not realizing it would mess up my floats. So I'm not really sure what to do. I'd rather not absolute position the two columns if I can avoid it. This website is more or less completely coded and I only found out about the need for the sidebar to scroll in the last leg of the process. So it's kind of a PITA to do too much to it.

So essentially I need a way to make a floated DIV to act as though it's under the affects of `position:fixed`

My thought was ideally maybe a javascript/jQuery solution that just latches onto the div and makes magic happen? But I'm open to a CSS solution if it's a quick/easy one.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954759/jquery-scroll-sidebar

Comment: what exactly is the problem making it so you can't use a fixed position? what happens that you don't want to have happen? if you tell us more we can help.

Comment: How are you setting your width and height. Is it in percentage or px/em?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that your problem with making the sidebar `position: fixed` is that it takes it out of the flow, so your main content shifts over to the left, under the sidebar. If that's a correct interpretation, then add `margin-left` to the main content with the same width as the sidebar, e.g.:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}
.content {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

With only two columns, there's no need to float the main content. Adjust as needed for your particular situation (e.g. change units to `em` or whatever).

Comment: With this I ended up with the problem of the sidebar tucking behind t he content. But I just added a margin to it so it could clear the content and it works wonderfully. Thank you!